# How to set default warning level to most strict one while working in C in Visual Studio Express 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Some people advised me to set the compiler warning level to the most strict level for the health of my programs but I can't find it where I can set it. I searched for an hour but all pages about this mentions about setting project specific. I want like when I open a new project, by default my warning level becomes the highest. Do you know how to achieve this? (I am writing C programs)

Comment: You'd have to create your own project template to get it preset like you want.  Pretty doubtful that Express supports that.  If you don't see File + Export Template then stop looking or start considering getting the retail edition.

Comment: below link explains the solution http://mihai-nita.net/2010/05/10/changing-default-vs-warning-level/